# sql server trigger for insert

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I am new to Sql Server but I have always used Oracle a lot. I see that some functionalities are not suppported in Sql Server. Lets say, I want to watch a table for insertion, and what is inserted into that table, I want to copy that same inserted row into another table.

here is my code

```
Create TRIGGER Post_Trigger ON Posts For Insert
AS
INSERT INTO EmailQueueRaw (UserID,CreatedBy,EmailTypeId,EmailTablePrimaryKey)    VALUES('','Arif','1','1');
GO
```

In Oracle, I used to use New and Old function which are great. But we dont have it in Sql Server and I am not sure what to do here. Please help me how to copy the same data to another table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `INSERTED` (and, if needed `DELETED`) but you need to be aware that they are [pseudo-tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191300.aspx) and could contain 0, 1, or multiple rows:

```
Create TRIGGER Post_Trigger ON Posts For Insert
AS
INSERT INTO EmailQueueRaw (UserID,CreatedBy,EmailTypeId,EmailTablePrimaryKey)
SELECT '',ColumnA,'1',ColumnB FROM inserted;
GO
```

Comment: how can it have multiple rows? if the case was update or delete statement, there might be multiple rows, but not on insert. because on insert there is only one row inserted at a time, but update and delete might affect multiple rows.

Comment: @Borsel - In *general* an `INSERT` can affect multiple rows. SQL Server syntax for all versions allows `INSERT ... SELECT` (in fact, I've shown one inside the trigger in my answer). ANSI standard syntax allows multiple tuples in the `VALUES` clause, e.g. `INSERT INTO Table(A,B) VALUES (1,2),(3,4)` and is supported since 2008 version (IIRC). Oracle has long supported the ANSI standard syntax, I believe.

Comment: @Borsel (Actually, on further reflection, I believe `INSERT ... SELECT` is also allowed by the standard, it's not an SQL Server only construct)